# How to pass multi dimensional array in MQL5 CopyBuffer function?

Tags: arrays, mql5

I'm trying to pass an array stored in a multi-dimensioned array, to the copyBuffer function which accepts an array as a parameter, as follows;

```
int handle_iMA[10];
double arr_iMA[10][50];

CopyBuffer(handle_iMA[0],0,0,50,arr_iMA[0]);
```

I'm getting compile error 'Invalid array access' at the 'arr_iMA[0]' of the last line.

I can define a single array for each iMA and pass it to the function without any problem. But I need to keep the array in the multidimensional array for easier access.

Can someone please point me in the right direction to achieve this? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`CopyBuffer()` in MQL5 uses array handles, you are trying to directly use arrays. You are also mixing array types (`int` and `double`) which will lead to data loss. The easiest way to copy simple arrays would be

```
double array1[10];
double array2[10][50];

for(int i=0; i<=ArrayRange(array1,0)-1; i++) array2[i][0]=array1[i];
```

Comment: I can't understand how I mixed array types? The first array handle_iMA is not passed to the function, and it only accepts a handle value. I just pass the handle value stored in the first array to the function. There is no error on that. And there is no connection between the first array and the second array. The first parameter just accepts an integer value. Problem with the second array which is multi-dimensional. Thanks.

Comment: int  CopyBuffer( 
   int       indicator_handle,     // indicator handle 
   int       buffer_num,           // indicator buffer number 
   int       start_pos,            // start position 
   int       count,                // amount to copy 
   double    buffer[]              // target array to copy 
   );

Comment: An array handle does not contain `[]`. See the following link for examples [https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/series/copybuffer](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/series/copybuffer)

Comment: As per the documentation in the link above, you can only use a singe dimensional array with `CopyBuffer()` and the indicator handle can not be passed from an array.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I referred to the documentation before asking the question. But I expected there should be some way to define array within array for the parameter:  double buffer[]. Anyway thanks.